# #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row - SQL Error

Tags: mysql, sql

Why I get this error, because it seems the subquery returns only the column product_id:

```
UPDATE `product_category` SET `winner` = 

(SELECT product_id FROM 

(SELECT product.product_id, product.category FROM ranking JOIN product JOIN test 
WHERE ranking.product = product.product_id AND ranking.test = test.test_id AND ranking.rang = 1 
GROUP BY product.product_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(product.product_id) DESC, product.price, product.name) AS winners 

    GROUP BY winners.category ORDER BY winners.category)
```

Why does it not work, because the whole table which returns in () has only one column?

Comment: Do you really want to know why, or would you rather just solve the problem? If the latter, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: It returns many rows

Comment: Your update statement expects only one row and it will be set to all rows in category table.  You should do  the join along with the update statement to get what you need

Comment: The error says that your subquery returns more than one *row* not *column*. You could add a `LIMIT 1` after  `ORDER BY winners.category`. But be careful since you are updating *all* rows in `product_category`.